# making a class with abstraction is also encapsulation?

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation, abstraction

Encapsulation is said to be wrapping up of data and method and hidding functionality(method and instance variable) that is not needed for outside of this object

my question is only making a variable private and public is encapsulation ? or making a class with abstraction is also encapsulation ?

For Example:
I have Switch(Electic Switch) class doing on or off 
to make a Switch class i have used abstraction
and i encapsulated Switch class with using abstraction so that i can map 
motor or bulb or any electric Instrument

```
public class Switch {
    private boolean isOff = true;
    private ISwitchListener listener;
    public Switch(ISwitchListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
    public void trigger() {
        isOff = !isOff;    
        if(isOff) {
            listener.off();
        } else {
            listener.on();
        }
    }
}

public class Bulb implements ISwitchListener {

    @Override
    public void on() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("bulb is glittering");
    }

    @Override
    public void off() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("bulb is not glittering");
    }

}

public interface ISwitchListener {
    public void on();
    public void off();
}

public class Executor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Switch swt = new Switch(new Bulb()); 
        swt.trigger();          
    }
}
```

if i am not using abstraction here , i would have class like below

```
public class Switch {
    private boolean isOff = true;
    public void trigger() {

        isOff = !isOff;
        Bulb b =new Bulb();
        if(isOff) {
            b.off();
        } else {
            b.on();
        }
    }
}
```

When i want to map Motor to Switch i need to change class as bleow

```
public class Switch {
    private boolean isOff = true;
    public void trigger() {

        isOff = !isOff;
        Bulb b =new Bulb();
        if(isOff) {
            b.off();
        } else {
            b.on();
        }
    }
}


public class Motor {
    public void on() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Motor is rotating");
    }

    public void off() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Motor is getting off to rotate");
    }
}
```

Comment: It hides implementation not functionality, hiding functionality doesn't make much sense.

Comment: "making a variable private and public" A variable can't be both. "making a class with abstraction" I don't know what this means.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no, abstraction and encapsulation are two different things. Specifically, abstraction means removing detail that is unnecessary for the intended purpose of the code or model. For example, if you write a program to calculate how much paint you need for a house, your model of a house needs to include the surface area, but doesn't need to include the address, or the size of the yard. 
Encapsulation means hiding the internal workings of an object or module, such that the coupling between objects can be controlled and readily changed. If there were no encapsulation, clients of the object might directly reference its internal elements, which would mean that you would have to change all the clients if you modified the object.

Regarding the code example, I think a better solution would be to create an interface "Switchable" and have Motor and Bulb implement it. Like so:

```
public interface Switchable {
   void on();
   void off();
}

public class Motor implements Switchable {
    public void on() {
        System.out.println("Motor is rotating");
    }

    public void off() {
        System.out.println("Motor is getting off to rotate");
    }
}

public class Switch {
    private boolean isOff = true;
    private Switchable switchable;

    public Switch(Switchable switchable) {
        this.switchable = switchable;
    }

    public void trigger() {
        isOff = !isOff;
        if(isOff) {
            switchable.off();
        } else {
            switchable.on();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is an example for dependency injection => you let the caller decide which concrete class the class "Switch" needs to do its job.

In fact it is the "opposite" of data hiding as the outside world has to know some implementation details of the class "Switch". => it needs an implementation of ISwitchListener

Answer (score 0):

As @T I said, it can be a method hiding for example from Java 8 you can create default implementation in the interface, so you can hide that in the class where implement the interface.

But encapsulation is about field (instance variable) hiding. Creating a private member (instance variable) and creating setter and getter. You will reach the value only via dedicated methods.

If you want to encapsulate your methods, you need to deal with accessibility (see default and protected modifiers).

So the answer for your question is: No. Making a class with abstraction is not encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Abstraction and Encapsulation are interrelated. You can say Abstraction is needed to Encapsulate the system. 
**Abstraction** is when a client system does not need to know more than what is in the interface. 
**Encapsulation** is when a client of a module is not able to know more than what is in the interface.

Pleas refer this [page](http://www.hemantjha.in/content/3/abstraction-and-encapsulation.html) for a beautiful article on this  topic.